# Regex for the tokenizing the String "My foo has "zero" number",sugar,"My bar has "one number""

Tags: java, regex, parsing, lexer

I am trying to tokenize the String in java

```
"My foo, has "zero" number", sugar ,"My bar has "one or more" numbers"
```

Output should be like

```
"My foo, has "zero" number"
,
sugar
,
"My bar has "one or more" numbers"
```

Also i am using named capturing group to match them.

```
String[] p = new String[3];
    p[0] = "(?<Special>[\\[\\]/.$*\\-+=><#()%,!|&{}])"; 
    p[1] = "(?<Literals>\"[^\"]*\")"; 
    p[2] = "(?<Identifiers>\\w+)";
for (String s: p) {
        sb.append(String.format("|(%s)", s)); 
    } //for ends here

    Pattern tp = Pattern.compile(new String(sb.substring(1))); // adding the patterns one after another separated by |

    Matcher m = tp.matcher(line);

    while (m.find()) { //searches if a token is matched.
    if ((m.group("Special") != null)) {
            System.out.println(m.group("Special"));
            continue;
        }
    else if((m.group("Literals") != null)) {
            System.out.println(m.group("Literals"));
            continue;
        }
    else if((m.group("Identifiers") != null)) { 
            System.out.println(m.group("Identifiers"));
            continue;
        }
    }
```

I am able to tokenize sugar(using it to match identifiers) using (\w+) and , (using the regex in special). However for literals i am not able to match the group, i guess because of the inner quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't your inner quotes be escaped? What is the rule that prevents `"My foo, has "` from being your first token?

Comment: Yes it should have escaped but it does not. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a different approach. `String.split()` in Java can take a regex argument, and if you split on this pattern:

```
("\s*)?,(?(1)|\s*")
```

It'll spit out the array you want (minus the commas). The way it works is it'll match a comma that's either preceded or followed by a quotation mark (but not both). It does this using a [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) (the `(?(1)|...)`, which will match its pattern if the first capturing group *does not* match).

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YZN6mE/1)

Comment: This doesn't work because it consumes a quote from the desired outout.

Answer (score 0):

When the input has balanced quotes, the trick is to only split on a comma when there's an *even* number of quotes after it:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" *, *(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

See [Java live demo](https://ideone.com/NFBrYU) producing the desired output.

See [regex live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ofhfSIeSfjXVUi) too.